# WCF and Web Service Descriptions

Tags: wcf, web-services, presentation

Generally in a Web Service when you navigate to the .asmx you would get a list of the operations then be able to click on them and get the details for the call such as the parameters to pass in and its returns. Very useful for the clients and anyone that needs to call the Service externally.

However, in WCF the .svc brings up something entirely different and hard to decipher without the use of a tool. Is there a way to get WCF to present these services like old Web Service or is such a feature been completely removed and do the developers have to use a tool like Storm?

Comment: You can generate WSDL metadata by configuring your service - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997781/when-to-use-wcf-mex-endpoint.

Comment: The help page has been removed in WCF. It was of very little use - it was of no value for parameters of complex types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coworker had a fairly simple solution that has worked well.

I created a SOAP web service and then through that service I call WCF service. Users will only see and interact with SOAP which is easier for them to understand and then the web service will pass the data on to the WCF.

Answer (score 0):

you can create matadataexchenge endpoint and anyone will can create proxy classes or look at interface by `../visual_studio/common7/ide/WcfTestClient.exe`